# Auth::check() works only in middleware laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem that I need to check if the user is authenticated but Auth::check() always returns me false even if I'm authorizated

```
    public function __construct(AffiliateRepository $affiliateRepo)
    {
//        $this->middleware(['guest', 'maintenance_mode'])->except(['indexPage']);
//        $this->middleware(['prohibited_demo_mode'])->only('register');
        dd(auth()->check());

        $this->affiliateRepo = $affiliateRepo;
    }
```

this always returns me false. Can somebody help me?

Comment: "Auth::check() always returns me false even if I'm authorizated" - so how you prove that you are authorized if Laravel, via `auth()->check()`, is saying you aren't?

Comment: are you using a different guard to authenticate on your app ? if so, you need to use  `auth('<guard_name>')->check()`

Comment: I'm using default guard

Comment: You can't use `Auth::check()` in the constructor as of 5.3. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) and the linked duplicate.

Comment: Now I know thank you for help

Comment: what's your guard name when you're login